# Octal string literals and octal command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an octal string `"\334\n\226"` (the `\n` is not in octal because it has a printable ASCII representation). I would like to encode this in a bytes array, so I would like to convert `"\334\n\226"` -> `[\334, \n, \226]` -> `[220, 10, 150]`. I thought to write the following code:

```
octal_string = "\334\n\226"
encoded_string = octal_string.encode()
for b in encoded_string:
  print(b)
```

This outputs:

> 195
>   156
>   10
>   194
>   150

Additionally I would like to pass this string as a command line argument to my script so if I write the script:

```
import sys

octal_string = sys.argv[1]
encoded_string = octal_string.encode()
for b in encoded_string:
  print(b)
```

Then I run:

```
> python3 myscript.py \334\n\226
```

I get:

> 51
>   51
>   52
>   110
>   50
>   50
>   54

How am I supposed to do this?

Comment: As I understand you want the output to be `220 10 150`. Can you use regex?

Comment: Have you tried encoding as latin1 ?

Comment: @Benjy Kessler I've edited my codes below.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex or this code with list comprehension, split() and the int() method:

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 2:

    s=sys.argv[1]
    print(s)
    print(s.split("\\"))
    rslt=[ 10 if e=="n" else int(e,8) for e in s.split("\\") if e ]
    print(rslt)
```

The quotation marks are important:

```
$ python3 myscript.py "\334\n\226"
\334\n\226
['', '334', 'n', '226']
[220, 10, 150]
```

EDIT:
In Python3 this code works:

```
b= bytes(sys.argv[1],"utf8")
print(b)
#rslt= [ ord(c) for c in str(b,"unicode-escape") ]
rslt= [ ord(c) for c in b.decode("unicode-escape") ]
print(rslt) 

b'\\334\\ne\\226'
[220, 10, 101, 150]
```

EDIT2:

```
import ast

s= ast.literal_eval("'"+sys.argv[1]+"'")  # It interprets the escape sequences,too.
print( [ord(c) for c in s ] )

[220, 10, 101, 150]
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the generic case: Let's say "\340\ne\002" then e should be parsed as 101 since e in ASCII is 101. There shouldn't be a need to implement this from scratch. I think these should be valid string literals (see https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html \334 should be a valid character)